# Problem with latest nvidia driver provided by Canonical

Tags: 12.04, nvidia

I got on my workstation Ubuntu 12.0.4.4.
Today I noticed that new nvidia driver is available on official repo so I made and upgrade of Nvidia driver from nvidia-309-updated to nvidia-331.

Update process went quite smooth but after reboot I saw message from Xorg that Im in a troubleshooting mode and my card needs to be reconfigured.
My graphic card is GeForce GTX 770 and here is my [Xorg.log]: https://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=XUswx1r1.

Funny is the fact is I start system in a recovery mode and than I select option "Resume boot in a normal way" all is fine. 
I already tried to reconfigure all nvidia packages apt-get install --reinstall nvidia*

Any ideas ?

Comment: `apt-get install --reinstall [package]` does not reconfigure packages as far as I know, `dpkg-reconfigure [package]` should be the right command. I can only see that you should check `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` in the logfile you posted, but that file may have already been rotated whe you are reading this so you should also look and older files.

Comment: The "current" proprietary driver for Nvidia still is version 304 in 12.04. In case you have issues with a newer driver you may have to purge this driver to revert back to `nvidia-current`.

Comment: Takka: I disagree. currently Conanical provides in a a official package Nvidia driver in version 331. Nvidia current points to even older version (295.40). Yes Im aware I can go back to some old version. Deal is that nvidia driver in version lower than 319 does not work correctly with my graphic card (36hours bug - I experienced this bug already). Anyway thx for suggestion

Comment: LiveWireBT: log I provided is the correct one (dont worry about the file name :) )

Comment: what I noticed. After system is boot up in  failsave mode (no unity  but only an error message that my graphic card need to be reconfigured) I can bring graphic interface up by restarting lightdm in a console.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having problems with that update too! 
I used to use the 319 drivers in Ubuntu, but since the update, I'm now using the 304!

Can I just uninstall it and use the new one (331.20)?

Answer (score 0):

after installing new Nvidia driver make sure X has been configured to use the new driver, for this run in Terminal:

```
sudo nvidia-xconfig
```

after reboot the system and then run:

```
gksudo nvidia-settings
```

To make sure you start nvidia-settings

Comment: thx for info. xorg.conf is on place and it looks the same like the precious version (before upgrade). Vnvidia module is aliased as "nvidia"